# code for DLookup for login username and password

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I want to make a log-in form, but I don't know how to get or confirm that what I typed in my Username and password textbox is in my table using DLookup in my log-in button.

Here's my current code:

```
Dim u As Variant
Dim p As Variant
Dim inu As String
Dim inp As String

u = DLookup("cusername", "tbl_users", "inuser.Value")
p = DLookup("cpassword", "tbl_users", "inpass.Value")

inu = inuser.Value
inp = inpass.Value

If inu = u And inp = p Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_userlog"
MsgBox "Welcome " & tuser & "!"

ElseIf IsNull(Me.inuser.Value) And inpass.Value = 1 Then
MsgBox "You must input a username"

ElseIf IsNull(Me.inpass.Value) And inuser.Value = 1 Then
MsgBox "you must input a password"

ElseIf IsNull(Me.inuser.Value) And IsNull(Me.inpass.Value) Then
MsgBox "you must input a username and password"

Else
MsgBox "The username or password you entered is invalid"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use a where condition in the password look up to select by the correct username. I have code for this at work including basic password encryption which I can post tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

The third [DLookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) argument, *criteria*, is an optional string expression which is similar to a *"WHERE clause in an SQL expression, without the word WHERE"*.

In yours, you seem to be trying to give it the value of a control named `inuser`.  However you're actually passing a string which contains the text *"inuser.Value"*.

```
DLookup("cusername", "tbl_users", "inuser.Value")
```

But that won't give you what you want even if you remove the quotes.

If you want to look up `cusername` from `tbl_users` where some field (perhaps `user_id`) matches `inuser.Value` ...

```
DLookup("cusername", "tbl_users", "user_id = " & inuser.Value)
```

If that field, `user_id`, is text rather than numeric data type, build quotes into the *criteria* string ...

```
DLookup("cusername", "tbl_users", "user_id = '" & inuser.Value & "'")
```

It looks to me like you have the same type of issue with `DLookup("cpassword", ...)`, so if I got the first one right, make a similar change there.

You can find more information about `DLookup` at [Description of DLookup() usage, examples, and troubleshooting in Access 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786).  Although that's an old article, everything still applies to recent Access versions AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment I use this:

```
Private Sub cmdlogin_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.cb_user) Then
        MsgBox "You didn't select a user", vbCritical, "Error"
        Me.cb_user.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsNull(Me.txtpass) Then
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a password", vbCritical, "Error"
            Me.txtpass.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If encrypt(Me.txtpass.Value) = DLookup("password", "users", "user_id = " & Me.cb_user.Value) Then
                DoCmd.OpenForm ("home")
                Me.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox "Incorrect password. Please try again", vbCritical, "Incorrect password"
                Me.txtpass = Null
                Me.txtpass.SetFocus
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Where `cb_user` is a combo box of user names.

`Encrypt` is the basic ROT 13 encryption which I place in a module:

```
Public Function encrypt(strInput As String)
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer
    n = 13
    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        Mid(strInput, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(strInput, i, 1)) + n)
    Next i
    encrypt = strInput
End Function
```

If that isn't necessary omit the `encrpyt` wrap around the password lookup such that:

```
If encrypt(Me.txtpass.Value) = DLookup("password", "users", "user_id = " & Me.cb_user.Value) Then
```

becomes

```
If Me.txtpass.Value = DLookup("password", "users", "user_id = " & Me.cb_user.Value) Then
```