# How to go to a specific user's record after entering username/password in a login form

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to make a login page for a university system and have become hopelessly stuck on getting the database to open a user's specific form if they have already registered their details. e.g. the following code is for an "Edit Profile" button, so it would need to open the specific user's record rather than what it currently does which is just "docmd.openform "StudentF".  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub EditProfileLF_Click()
'Dimensions

Dim correctpassword As String
Dim registereduser As String
Dim studentnumberLen As Integer

'Trims and Ucase
Trim (StudentPasswordLF)
Trim (StudentNumberLF)
UCase (StudentNumberLF)

'No Student Number
If IsNull(StudentNumberLF) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Your Student Number", vbOKOnly, "Student Number Required"
Exit Sub
End If

'No Password
If IsNull(StudentPasswordLF) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Your Password", vbOKOnly, "Password Required"
Exit Sub
End If

'Invalid Student Number
studentnumberLen = Len(StudentNumberLF)

If studentnumberLen < 7 Or studentnumberLen > 7 Or IsNumeric(Left(StudentNumberLF, 1)) Or Not (IsNumeric(Right(StudentNumberLF, 6))) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter a Valid Student Number, See FAQ for Help", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Student Number"
Exit Sub
End If

'Password Check
correctpassword = DLookup("[PasswordST]", "StudentT", "[StudentNumber]='" & Me.StudentNumberLF.Value & "'")


If StudentPasswordLF = correctpassword Then

DoCmd.OpenForm "StudentF"


Else

MsgBox "Incorrect Password, if you have forgotten your Password click 'Forgot Your Password'"

Exit Sub

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hopefully this is just proof-of-concept code, because storing passwords in clear-text is NOT a good idea.

Comment: DoCmd.OpenForm will accept a record filter as a parameter.  Use that to open up the form to the correct record.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638803/496736

Comment: Can't quite get my head around the post you linked. If the username login box is called "StudentNumber" and I'm trying to open a record from the Form "StudentF" could you give an example of how it would be coded? Been stuck on this awhile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would use a filter:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "StudentF", , , "[StudentNumber]='" & Me.StudentNumberLF.Value & "'"
```

In the form properties for StudentF, ensure that "Filter On Load" is set to "Yes".

Note that your DLookup will return Null if the student does not have a record in the DB. It would be better to use DCount to test student # and password together, rather than retrieving the password from the DB and comparing it in code.

Also, here is a neat way to validate StudentNumber for the correct format:

```
  'Invalid Student Number
  With New RegExp                         
      .Pattern = "^[A-Z][0-9]{6}$"       ' one upper-case letter + six digits
      If Not .Test(StudentNumberLF) Then
          MsgBox "Please Enter a Valid Student Number, See FAQ for Help"
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End With
```

To enable RegExp got to Tools > References and check "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions".